# How secure is password_hash

Tags: php, security, hash, authentication, passwords

So basically i am taking a course of web development where the tutor said we need to hash the password before storing it in mysql so that hackers cannot decode it.

the way we do it is

```
$hashedPassword = password_hash ("myPassword", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

and to decode while on the login form we use

```
password_verify("somePassword", $hashedPassword);
```

so my question is, if someone hacks into my mysql database and steals the hashed password, wont he also be able to decode it ? is it safe to use to make a website login ?

Comment: The `password_verify()` function does not "decode" the hash at all, since that simply is not possible. A hash algorithm is a one way process, it cannot be reversed, that is the whole point. Instead it hashes the provided password and compares the two hashes. That does not mean that it is impossible to break such a hash, especially if you get hold of it as an attacker. But you cannot simply decode it, you need to perform a brute force attack.

Comment: Please refer to http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: `password_hash()` is currently the best way to accomplish this. Kudos to your tutor for knowing this and not being one of the million sources that teach you to use something horribly outdated.

Comment: _"wont he also be able to decode it"_ Not in any reasonable amount of time. _"is it safe to use to make a website login"_ Yes.

Comment: Here's a my password hashed using password hash `$2y$10$usX/K4jE3tMWvQt.fdimNuV9twBuWO6ANSlESwuKlRNPFAt1DJYCu` feel free to try and decode it.

Comment: @arkascha "Instead it hashes the provided password and compares the two hashes." I appreciate if you clarify to me how. (I understand the two hashes are different, how is  is that they encode the same plain password? how does we check that?)

Comment: @mario: The hashes are identical if passwords are identical.

(You've probably long forgotten about the question, but I'll answer it just for a closure here.)